# fluentd Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError error="pattern not matched with data

Tags: fluentd

I am using 1.24 version EKS. I am using the below fluentd config and I am getting below error. I tried with many format combinations but nothing worked.

```
2023-02-16 21:02:57 +0000 [warn]: #0 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError error="pattern not matched with data '{\"app\":\"JavaApp\",\"time\":\"2023-02-16T19:21:50.206+00:00\",\"logger\":\"com.example.App\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"class\":\"org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger\",\"method\":\"logStarted\",\"file\":\"StartupInfoLogger.java\",\"line\":61,\"thread\":\"main\",\"msg\":\"Started App in 7.718 seconds (JVM running for 10.822)\"}'" location=nil tag="kubernetes.var.log.containers.java-app-78b5d9c689-btm25_default_java-app-dc08d83479a29fe04e193b0b3b93b20aa61ad3b8746f11617f7ca5ae3e59d948.log" time=2023-02-16 19:21:50.237968502 +0000 record={"stream"=>"stdout", "logtag"=>"F", "log"=>"{\"app\":\"JavaApp\",\"time\":\"2023-02-16T19:21:50.206+00:00\",\"logger\":\"com.example.App\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"class\":\"org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger\",\"method\":\"logStarted\",\"file\":\"StartupInfoLogger.java\",\"line\":61,\"thread\":\"main\",\"msg\":\"Started App in 7.718 seconds (JVM running for 10.822)\"}"}
2023-02-16 21:02:57 +0000 [warn]: #0 no patterns matched tag="kubernetes.var.log.containers.java-app-78b5d9c689-btm25_default_java-app-dc08d83479a29fe04e193b0b3b93b20aa61ad3b8746f11617f7ca5ae3e59d948.log"
```

Here is my config,

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd-forwarder-cm
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: forwarder
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: fluentd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fluentd
    helm.sh/chart: fluentd-1.3.0
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: fluentd
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
data:
  fluentd.conf: |
 
    # Ignore fluentd own events
    <match fluent.**>
        @type null
    </match>
 
    # HTTP input for the liveness and readiness probes
    <source>
        @type http
        port 9880
    </source>
 
    # Throw the healthcheck to the standard output instead of forwarding it
    <match fluentd.healthcheck>
        @type null
    </match>
 
    # Get the logs from the containers running in the node
    <source>
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/*java-app*.log
      pos_file /opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/fluentd-docker.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
          @type multi_format
          <pattern>
            format regexp
            time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
            expression /^(?<time>.+)(?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>.)? (?<log>.*)/
        </pattern>
      </parse>
    </source>
 
    <filter **>
      @type parser
      key_name log
      <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
          format json
          time_key time
          time_type string
          time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"
          keep_time_key true
        </pattern>
      </parse>
    </filter>
 
    # enrich with kubernetes metadata
    <filter kubernetes.**>
        @type kubernetes_metadata
    </filter>
```

I even tried in Fluentulor to make sure the parsing works.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error contains the JSON part only and that is what the pattern is being matched against. The timestamp, stream, and log tag parts are missing. You need to make sure that you're getting input data from the correct source and that it has the format that you configured it for.